# Android Studio Firebase updateChildren

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Good day everyone. I'm having hard time time in Android Studio and Firebase, whenever I try to use updateChildren, it keeps on replacing the old one. I thought it would remain the old data inside the node, here is the code:

```
private void getClosestDriver() {
    DatabaseReference driverLocation = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("driversAvailable");
    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(driverLocation);

    geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(pickupLocation.latitude, pickupLocation.longitude), radius);

    geoQuery.removeAllListeners();

    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            if (!driverFound && requestBol) {
                driverFound = true;
                driverFoundID = key;

                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Driver").child(driverFoundID).child("passengerRequest");
                String passengerID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

                HashMap map = new HashMap();
                map.put("passengerRideID", passengerID);
                map.put("destination", destination);
                ref.updateChildren(map);

                getDriverLocation();
                mRequest.setText("Looking for Bus Location....");
            }
        }
```

Am I doing the right thing about the HasMap?

Comment: What exactly were you expecting to be retained after the call to updateChildren?

Comment: If you say it is replacing the old one, ok but what do want to achieve? You want to be added as a new child?

Comment: I want to retain the old one

Comment: Inside the PassengerRequest there should be a chils named passengerRideId and Destination but it keeps on replacing the old one whenever I try to save new data

Comment: I figured it out by adding the .child(passengerID)
`String passengerID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Driver").child(driverFoundID).child("passengerRequest").child(passengerID);
                `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

by changing it into

```
String passengerID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Driver").child(driverFoundID).child("passengerRequest").child(passengerID);


            HashMap map = new HashMap();
            map.put("destination", destination);
            ref.updateChildren(map);
```